# How to merge multiple files on an irregular index with forward fill in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

**Background:**

I have time sequence data across several csv files that each contain different kinds of sensor features. I am trying to merge the features in these files together on a common timestamp index.

The complication I've been having trouble with is that the timestamp a row of data was logged with does not correspond with some regular interval, but instead appears to correspond to the time that a sensor updated its value.

**Question:**

I am looking for a way to merge these files together in a "forward-fill"-like way where if a dataset does not have an an entry for a given timestamp, it would fill with the previous entry's values.

For example, if my two data files were

```
A.csv
time  X1  X2
  00   1   2
  01   3   4
  02   5   6
  03   7   8

B.csv
time  X3  X4
  00  10  11
  02  12  13
```

I would like a final dataset with values

```
time  X1  X2  X3  X4
  00   1   2  10  11
  01   3   4  10  11
  02   5   6  12  13
  03   7   8  12  13
```

that I could pipe into my tensorflow estimator.

I have attempted merging different CsvDatasets together, but it seems like it is not possible to "pause" a dataset iterator on a value to propagate it and merge it with the other dataset iterators in the way that I want.

(I know that I could do this with pandas by outer-joining on the time index and then doing pd.ffill, but I believe that I would then need the whole dataset in memory, which I am trying to avoid. I don't think loading the data in chunks is an option, either, due to the irregular time index.)

Does anyone know the best way to create a pipeline like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the merge in pandas by taking advantage of the fact that `pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)` defaults to merging on the indexes of `A` and `B`, and then `ffill` the result.

Example:

```
A = pd.read_csv('A.csv')
B = pd.read_csv('B.csv')

A = A.set_index('time')
B = B.set_index('time')

res = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1).ffill()
res
```

The print of `res` is:

```
      X1  X2    X3    X4
time                    
0      1   2  10.0  11.0
1      3   4  10.0  11.0
2      5   6  12.0  13.0
3      7   8  12.0  13.0
```